# 3D Building high LOD

Tags: data-request, buildings

I'm working on a project with 3d buildings and looking for high LOD 3d buildings like this

[image]

[image]

Where can I get these high LOD buildings?

Answer (score 0):

My first go-to for 3d models is TurboSquid.com.  Try this link:

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-model/free/commercial-building?synonym=commercial+buildings